# Current WordPress Page Title as Search Parameter into A Tag <a href="www.domain.com/s?=currentpagetitle"></a>

Tags: php, html, wordpress

i would like to include an affiliate link as a widget which inserts the title of the respective page as search parameter.

```
<a href="www.amazon.com/s?=titleofthepage">Link</a>
```

I have already created a shortcode in the functions.php with get_the_title

```
function post_title_shortcode(){
$variable = get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode('post_title','post_title_shortcode');
```

and it is called [post_title]

However

```
<a href="www.amazon.de/s?=[post_title]"></a>
```

didn't work. Does anyone have any other idea how to make this happen?

Comment: you may need to show how you use the shortcode in the context of the template in addition to the final output.

Answer (score 0):

1-st you have to pass $post object/id in the [get_the_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) and 2-nd you have to actually echo this title so you can use it. So it should be something like:

```
function post_title_shortcode(){
  global $post;
  $variable = get_the_title($post->ID);
  echo $variable;
}
add_shortcode('post_title','post_title_shortcode');
```

But accessing global $post like this is not recomended, so better to use [get_queried_object()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/) and have something like:

```
function post_title_shortcode(){
    global $wp_query;
    $term = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    echo $term->post_title;
}
add_shortcode('post_title','post_title_shortcode');
```

where you'll get the current queried object and whatever you need from it.